# Socket isn't working in Python

Tags: python

I've been trying out the 'socket' module in Python but whenever I attempt to run this code :

```
import socket
import sys

host = '192.168.1.1'
port = 23

try:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except:
      print "socket() failed"
      sys.exit(1)
```

Then it dies. Here is the error without the except and try :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\socket.py", line 6, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

I've just started Python(Today) and am in need of help.

I saved it as socket.py but also sock.py ...

Comment: Yes .. But it wont work as sock.py either.

Comment: Make sure you delete `socket.py`. If that continues to fail, please update the stacktrace to the one you get with `sock.py`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import socket
```

[looks into the current directory before Python's standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). And since your file is called `socket.py`, it is itself imported instead of the [socket](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) standard library module. Rename (don't copy, since that would leave the original file) the file to something else, such as `my_socket.py`.

Comment: haha thanks. now I feel stupid. I'm a python newbie though so lesson learned :) +1