# Issue with socket module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't import socket module into my program. When I import it said, `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute "AF_INET'`.
I think there is a problem with my python virtual machine.

Comment: A common problem is naming your file something that would cross with the module. What did you name your file? Also, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly It is looking like Either naming problem or path problem.You can try to run your program from another location as did by this [Python Socket Problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=464541)

Or if it is a naming problem then maybe you are using some standard names in your code, which are clashes with system ones [Socket isn't working in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422356/socket-isnt-working-in-python) and [Python Error](http://programandolahuida.blogspot.in/2009/09/error-python-module-object-has-no.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb in users' created python modules, never give your modules the same python's standard modules names; instant conflict will occur.

eg. If you name your socket app "socket.py", and started your application, similar problem to what you showed will appear.